# Python3.x: Reading multiple columns in a csv file in a for-loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have numerous csv files in a folder that I want to analyze using python. Each csv file contains one set of y and multiple x values. For example, one csv file looks like the following. (all the csv files have the same number of x and y)

```
y    x1    x2    x3
1   0.5   0.1   2.0
2   1.0   0.2   3.0
3   2.5   0.7   0.5
4   0.4   1.2   0.1
5   0.2   4.0   9.0
6   1.2   5.0   0.2
```

I am reading all the csv files in the folder and attempted to read the y and x:

```
my_xlist=[x1,x2,x3] #these are string. 


for file in myfiles:
    my_y = []
    my_x = []

    with open('my_folder/'+file, 'r') as f:   
        data = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',') 
        for row in data:
            my_y.append(float(row[0]))
            my_x.append(float(row[1:len(my_xlist)])) #not sure about this line
```

Currently, it reads the x values by row.

The desired outcome is the followings (x values read by columns):

```
my_y=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
my_x=([0.1,1.0,2.5,0.4,0.2,1.2], [0.1,0.2,0.7,1.2,4.0,5.0], [2.0,3.0,0.5,0.1,9.0,0.2])
```

Could any of you help me reading all the columns for x?

Comment: You specify the delimiter as `','` but your data is not comma separated.

Comment: I'm confused. The x values are in `row[1:4]`, so what's preventing you from getting them? And what is `my_xlist` exactly?

Comment: @wjandrea, I fixed the my_xlist. They are really just the name of x, but they were numbers so it may have been confusing.

Comment: @wjandrea I have tried `row[1:4]`, but I get the following error message. `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`.

Comment: I'm still confused. `x1`-`x4` are not defined. Are they supposed to be strings? And yes, you obviously can't convert a list to a float. What is the output supposed to be? Please make a [mre].

Comment: @wjandrea I added an explanation that they `x1`-`x3` are string.

Comment: @user7852656 OK but they're still not defined, and anyway `my_xlist` is not used, so what are they supposed to do? For that matter what does `os.listdir` have to do with the problem? Again, you need to make a [mre].

Comment: @wjandrea The intended use for my_xlist is now incorporated. I also got rid of os.listdir, because it is not directly related to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Pandas to read csv. pandas read csv make DataFrame object which is very helpful for further operation with information. May be following code will help you.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

list_of_dataframe = []
for file in os.listdir("path/to/directory"):
    temp = pd.read_csv(str("path/to/directory/" + file))
    list_of_dataframe.append(temp)
df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframe) # This dataframe contains all information
```